# Upload script with output url insert into textbox to submit?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for my bad english.

I want a script, which have a image uploader, limit 2mb and one file per use, supported extensions: png, jpg, jpeg, gif. Size 468*70 only. And I need an upload button next to the text box which pastes an image link, and after the upload, it paste the image link to that text box. If user doesn't want to upload, he still can paste link on that and submit, i got my submit button, you can make your, I will recode that.

Image for eg:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzcxv.png

```
if(empty($_POST) == false) {
$_POST['ip'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ip'], ENT_QUOTES);
$_POST['port'] = (int)$_POST['port'];
$banner   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['banner'], ENT_QUOTES);

if($banner !== ''){
    $imageProp = @getimagesize($banner);
    if($imageProp == false){
        $errors[] = "Banner link is not an image!";
    }
    if($imageProp[0] !== 468 || $imageProp[1] !== 60){
        $errors[] = "Banner is too large or too small, only 468 * 60 accepted. Your image has: " .$imageProp[0]." * ".$imageProp[1];
    }
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Banner (468 * 60) </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="banner" class="span4" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: `getimagesize` needs to either see a local file, or a remote file by one of the supported streaming methods.  Maybe this example will help.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I guess you should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I have uploader script, but I don't know how to put it link to textinput which has name "banner" in my code. I want it put output link automaticly after upload completed. I want a button near that textinput

Comment: My script only has a text-input-box to put link on. After submit, server will check size of the banner. But i want a upload button near that, to browse file and upload it to my server, then check requirement. If passed, image link on my server is automaticly put to that text-input-box

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of PHP tutorials which can help you handle the backend workflow of the file upload. You could probably handle the filetype validation and filesize validation on the frontend.

Here's some Twitter Bootstrap for the frontend presentation of your form.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="submit.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" id="img">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="url" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="Or enter a URL...">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
</form>
```

[Learn more about Bootstrap's inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

After the user submits the form you can display the link to the image in a modal.

[Learn more about Bootstrap's modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)